# Prove that $7^n+2$ is divisible by $3$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

> Use mathematical induction to prove that $7^{n} +2$
>   is divisible by $3$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$.

I've tried to do it as follow.

If $n = 1$ then  $9/3 = 3$.
Assume it is true when $n = p$. Therefore $7^{p} +2= 3k $ where $k ∈ \mathbb{N} $. Consider now $n=p+1$. Then 
\begin{align}
&7^{p+1} +2=\\
&7^p\cdot7+ 2=\\
\end{align}
I reached a dead end from here. If someone could help me in the direction of the next step it would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you have $7^p=3k-2$ so...

Comment: already feeling ashamed for asking it. just needed a push. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If $7^n+2=3k$ then $$7^{n+1}+2=7(\color{red}{7^n})+2=7(\color{red}{3k-2})+2.$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $(7^{p+1}+2)-(7^p+2)=6\times7^p$.

Answer (score 2):

Step: n+1.

$7^{n+1}+2= (6+1)7^n+2=$

$ 6\cdot 7^n +(7^n+2).$

The first term is divisible by $3$, as is the second term (hypothesis).

Answer (score 1):

Show that $7^n\equiv 1 (\text{mod} 3)$

$(6 + 1)(6 + 1) = 36 + 12 + 1$

$(6 + 1)(6 + 1)(6 + 1) = 216 + 72 + 6 + 36 + 12 + 1$

So all $(6 + 1)^n$ involve the sum of a series of terms which are multiples of $6$ (divisible by $3$) except for the last term which is $1$

Hence $7^n\equiv 1 (\text{mod} 3)$

and $7^n + 2$ is always divisible by $3$

Answer (score 1):

*Conceptually* the inductive step gets $\,P(n\!+\!1)\,$ by scaling $\,P(n)\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{7 \equiv\,1}\pmod{\!3}\,$ using CPR = [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). If congruences are unknown we can preserve this *arithmetical* essence by using an analogous *product rule* for *divisibility* as below, where  $\ m\mid n\ $ means $\,m\,$ divides $\,n.\,$

$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\!\! \begin {align}
&3\mid\  \color{#c00}{7\ \ - \,\  1}\\
&3\mid\ \ \  7^{\large n} -\ B\qquad\ P(n)\qquad\ [B = -2\,\ {\rm in\  OP}]\\
\Longrightarrow\ \ &3\mid\ \color{#c00}7 7^{n}\! -\color{#c00}1B\qquad P(n\!+\!1)
\end{align} $$

$\begin{align}{\bf Divisibility\ Product\ Rule}\ \ \ \  
&m\mid\  a\ -\ b\qquad {\rm i.e.}\quad \   a\,\equiv\, b\\
&m\mid \ \ A\: -\: B\qquad\qquad \ A\,\equiv\, B\\
\Longrightarrow\ \ &\color{}{m\mid aA - bB}\quad  \Rightarrow\quad aA\equiv bB\!\pmod{\!m}\\[.2em]
{\bf Proof}\,\ \  m\mid (\color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b})A + b(\color{#0a0}{A\!-\!B}) &\,=\, aA-bB\ \ \text{by $\,m\,$ divides $\rm\color{#0a0}{green}$ terms by hypothesis.}\end{align}$

The point of using congruences (vs. divisibilities) is that it allows us to reuse our strong intuition about *operations* (vs. relations), e.g. the above congruence product rule is the analog of multiplying the equations $a =b,\ A = b\,$ to get $\,aA = bB,\,$ something which is less intuitive arithmetically when expressed in divisibility language. This will be clarified when one studies ring theory - where one learns [the relationship](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3418237/242) between congruences and quotient rings (here $\Bbb Z\bmod n\,\cong\, \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$)

You can find further discussion of these topic [many prior posts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a242%20%22divisibility%20product%20rule%22)

Answer (score 0):

$7^{n} +2$ is divisible by $3$ iff $7^{n} +2 - 3 = 7^{n} -1$ is divisible by $3$.

Now, $7^{n} -1 = (7-1)(7^{n-1}+7^{n-2}+\cdots+1)$ is even divisible by $6$.