# A rule for Ring and ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring, $I\in R$ an ideal and $f\in R[X]$ with $a\in R$. How do I show that in $R/I$:

$$f(a+I)=f(a)+I$$

Comment: Try showing that $f(a+i) - f(a) \in I$ for $i\in I$. You will need to use the fact that $I$ is an ideal. It's not hard to argue, but you might need an inductive argument. Here's what it would be for a quadratic function: $f(x) = x^2$, then $f(a+i) = (a+i)^2 = a^2 + ai + ia + i^2 = f(a) + i'$ for some $i'\in I$. I'm sure there's some isomorphism type theorem that argues this well, but I always think of algebra at its basest level arguments for whatever reason.

Comment: Write $f(a+x)$ in powers of $x$. This is, Taylor expansion at $a$, $f(a+x)=f(a)+f'(a)x+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}x^2+...+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}x^n$ for some $n$. Then, if $x\in I$ all the part $f'(a)x+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}x^2+...+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}x^n$ belongs to $I$.

Comment: @OscarRascal what about in non-zero characteristic ?

Comment: @KingDingeling are your rings commutative?

Comment: @peterag What about? The same, expand in powers of $x$.

Comment: @peterag: it is not stated but I think that we can assume that.

Comment: @OscarRascal e.g., in char $2$, look at the poly $x^2$. Then it is true that $(a+x)^2 = a^2 + x^2$, but your "Taylor series" expansion is problematic - $2! = 0$ in characteristic zero, so you can't divide by it - of course, $f^{(1)}(a)=f^{(2)}(a)$ (formal definition on polys, obviously - no limits ) also is equal to zero.

Comment: Note that this is the quotient-ring ideal-form of the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). It is hekpful to keep in mind the more general congruence analogs when learning such topics (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3418237/242) for more on the relationship between congruences and ideals for general algebraic structures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little weird to treat $f$, a formal polynomial with coefficients in $R$, as if it were a function, but let's pretend that [formal polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216470/what-is-a-formal-polynomial) implicitly invoke the evaluation map for this problem.

For some $d \geq 0$, there are $r_0, \dots r_d \in R$ such that 
$$  f = r_0 + \sum_{i=1}^d r_i X^i  \text{.}  $$
(You don't say that your rings have unit, so we can't assume that $R$ has a $1$ that $(a+I)^0$ can be, so we must split the constant term out of the sum.)  Then, implicitly use the evaluation map to treat $f$ as also an element of $\{ R[X] \times R \rightarrow R \}$, in fact, we need the generalization to sets as inputs and outputs, so an element of $\{ R[X] \times \mathscr{P}(R) \rightarrow \mathscr{P}(R) \}$, where $\mathscr{P}$ denotes powerset.  Then
$$  f(a + I) = r_0 + \sum_{i=1}^d r_i (a+I)^i  \text{,}  $$
a subset of $R$.  Clearly, $(a+I)^1 = a+I = a^1+I$.  Suppose, for $n \geq 1$, $(a+I)^n = a^n + I$.  Then (being careful about order of multiplication since you have not said your rings are commutative), \begin{align*}
(a+I)^{n+1} &= (a+I)(a+I)^n  \\
    &= (a+I)(a^n + I)  \\
    &= a(a^n + I) + I(a^n + I)  \\
    &= a^{n+1} + aI + Ia^n + I^2  \\
    &\subseteq a^{n+1} + I  \text{,}
\end{align*}
where in the last step we have used that $I$ is a (since you have not said otherwise, two-sided) ideal to recognize $aI \subseteq I$, $Ia^n \subseteq I$, and $I^2 \subseteq I$.  So, \begin{align*}
f(a + I) &\subseteq r_0 + \sum_{i=1}^d r_i (a^i+I)    \\
&\subseteq r_0 + \sum_{i=1}^d (r_ia^i + I)    \\
&= r_0 + \sum_{i=1}^d (r_ia^i) + \sum_{i=1}^d I    \\
&= f(a) + \sum_{i=1}^d I  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Since an ideal is closed under addition, $\sum_{i=1}^d I \subseteq I$.  Therefore, we have the relation $f(a+I) \subseteq f(a) + I$ among subsets of $R$.  Under the usual projection $R \rightarrow R/I$, since the right-hand side is contained in the coset of $I$ containing $f(a)$, we have
$$  f(a+I) = f(a) + I$$
in $R/I$.

Comment: Thank you very much!